# Do carrots cure cancer?

Tags: diet, cancer

**Do carrots cure cancer? **

There’s a lot of unsubstantiated information online about carrots and cancer.  There are even a few books.  What does science actually say about how carrots affect cancer risk?

Eg : “[Carrot juice to cure stage four cancer: the dangerous world of YouTube home remedies](https://www.newstatesman.com/politics/health/2019/02/youtube-cancer-treatments-dangerous-home-remedies-alternative-medecine)”

Comment: A more reasonable question would be whether carrots protects us from cancer.

Answer (score 1):

[One study from 1985](https://watermark.silverchair.com/32.pdf?token=AQECAHi208BE49Ooan9kkhW_Ercy7Dm3ZL_9Cf3qfKAc485ysgAAAmswggJnBgkqhkiG9w0BBwagggJYMIICVAIBADCCAk0GCSqGSIb3DQEHATAeBglghkgBZQMEAS4wEQQMNOhN34zYFZofHgm4AgEQgIICHo_Y0kejY4y9aF3EnVeZc4mjMUb4E4shtlDDUvCCX6TWRRzZ6SKVu2l0OGLMYpcYTLSx8bjbTSaOtwNViCANA6RrAE9nwXWtAtJh6w7-A6pG7kjBnuNVU390Xp5xJvsPeGuClWxvKqd23NbUy4HVxyNMOkV0TqREIxFaNPmNl7vQiVGd2pIajF_rs_FJy0KuQYYXb9hwFDKaNvwuVzYwyEG7VzcsEeugF_S9DRj5_P9TxfacO8HQn2X-WAbIW8rmOYtXd9I1qtgYf9OTJCGw-9KbrNACmhnnsOA_f_dwtx_DzcE_18-Je25eACftwLU017TqHvk93BvyTCl7GiUljC79lS1K-w4AYjKzgmJSgXB7odDxo_KDNexoggfNxHILS2S0blbwp-Zzxhqgo_cn843v8ewrlUPfqdUoMZG7EUYAOhCF8IWqefzE71DWKPecrFwONv8_5HZSBJ4dKDC4Xh1zAbXRkdOin3ZIBTz0jYD-7nkQuhm3zjtBgccEFfB8ViAY87-tomdRyg0qJFZngcipQfEfsesp1lXMhx7pgYTX9sAi0XkGRbaQDjcSQlcYCt5GUdNbgMp-atguuKsPWMCfLK422eTjKX7D41Pj-JNFt1aRBk1YotOUZMz7UhYXAfMDihYSu7LV98uHFY_bIeUqPhRsRbEukks43qdl2Nn9EdPdbSa9pqWbhlfmfN0XpQYL9XQEZd9WRxnjMPS1) shows that people who were in the top quintile of green and yellow vegetable intake had relative risk of 0.3 of dying from cancer compared to the lowest quintile. As far as risk for developing cancer, [in another study from the 1980s](https://watermark.silverchair.com/15-4-463.pdf?token=AQECAHi208BE49Ooan9kkhW_Ercy7Dm3ZL_9Cf3qfKAc485ysgAAAnAwggJsBgkqhkiG9w0BBwagggJdMIICWQIBADCCAlIGCSqGSIb3DQEHATAeBglghkgBZQMEAS4wEQQMZiyT1oxWRYKBf0ABAgEQgIICI9qyUJUO9gIewVcN1BY-kQfOE8UAffhyCNnso_7qdF3gz-GIPltSZAgozB1lAujVY8-s8qt4w-mWd-noCLW6cIwMdFqWst30tMFa841gmUYl2-Ssi4CAlj7EmRmPc7TfQnMcWk8aVZb0oDDaLifwGk0Bg9Pz4l35WIwrdJoq1fKtYpfEtV_xv-2qwQzBg6he6mbE4A9LUbnjZuBrEs66GsnmGKvhDEg06CBdMYR6BtJrbsoQeDIo-JP3EqIKxarwn4oU21jBhXT1hZcDnzyIYvgkXjj5TNhiYhFRh8ndqQkq9jjFPaa1SBNyJhZiZZEIjh8xgte9F3RQAaEL1--X3TZcTN5LKxqP1keXVFMXBbsUDG2BX2c3qU-_jcNN84gLa8WGNJI6ayUvK86uthptQazA_ei-JQluNsZEFkkELgCUuS3zij5nFiIHla9eUGKP6xqBp_tUAiP_QUCH7OdpOXqEtt_sF2b15ksGqk1xlAILVakR4RWB9CyGg5EqhItRT9gqAHAhdAxtuAtMfYYu1sJ2_P2LF76A7UfIbUT_RAsjSokG_7Td_v6h1lN9742zS9UGBFHmmTdu44nDEee313PG-bJACVAYi4Ny6PpchgZ_wE3nHdymBPydjzOatK6MhbQ_hVhg6Rh5wpm6vGerknDVrfjJ6jHzfvc0lmcLlBoog0-blWHCPuK02dzcBg4RGiwBu4QERg_y9y14V5R5IKxqYFQ), smokers who ate more carrots were less likely to develop lung cancer (this effect was only seen in smokers, not ex-smokers or non-smokers). Certainly not conclusive, and likely outdated, but interesting food for thought.

Comment: Wish I had an extra upvote for “food for thought” :) thanks